# Magento 2.1.8 Cart Rules

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.1.8

I have created 2 cart rules, and I want them to override each other if conditions are met.

The rules are:

> If quantity of products with attribute-set **`SHIRT`** is greater than 15, then give discount of 10%
>
> If quantity of products with attribute-set **`SHIRT`** is greater than 25, then give discount of 20%

I am giving the first rule priority 2 and the second rule priority 1.

I would expect that the second rule would override the first rule when quantity of products with attribute-set **`SHIRT`** is greater than **25**. But nothing happens, Magento just keeps giving 10% discount.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule still applies as the rule is in effect. Try setting a maximum on the first rule:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Attribute Set  is SHIRT
Quantity in cart  equals or greater than  10 
Quantity in cart  less than  25
```

Then leave the second rule alone. Of course, flush the cache before testing the new rules.